# Calling a method with a variable using spring-el from thymeleaf

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf, spring-el

I have something like this:

```
<form action="/" th:object="${index}">
<ul class="error" th:if="${#fields.hasAnyErrors()}" th:remove="all-but-first">
<li th:each="error : ${#fields.detailedErrors()}" th:utext="${index.fieldErrorText(error)}">DETAILED ERROR</li>
</ul>
</form>
```

Calling ${index.fieldErrorText(error)} works fine, but I want to go a step further. Since I have th:object="${index}" I want to be able to do something like this:

```
*{fieldErrorText(error)}
```

But in this case it looks for error on index rather than from the th:each variable and throws a "Property or field 'error' cannot be found".

I have tried other combinations: *{fieldErrorText(${error})} (Unexpected token. Expected 'rparen())' but was 'lcurly({)'), *{fieldErrorText(__${error}__)} (Cannot handle (241) 'ñ'; seems to do a toString or something) and *{fieldErrorText(__error__)} (Property or field 'error' cannot be found).

Does anybody know the right semantics for this case?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 *{fieldErrorText(__${error}__)}
```

According to the documentation you will need some pre-processing.

http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#preprocessing

Comment: Tried that. Sorry original message showed this as bold as I didn't escape my \_\_